# stoi undeclared even when using -std=c++11 flag with both g++ and clang++

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, compiler-errors

I have a very simple main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s = "194";
    int i = stoi(s);
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

In the command line `clang++ main.cpp -std=c++11` outputs:

```
main.cpp:6:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'stoi'
        int i = stoi(s);
                ^
1 error generated.
```

and `clang++ --version` outputs:

```
clang version 3.6.1 (tags/RELEASE_361/final)
Target: i686-pc-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

And with GCC, `g++ main.cpp -std=c++11` outputs:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:16: error: 'stoi' was not declared in this scope
  int i = stoi(s);
                ^
```

with `g++ --version` outputting:

```
g++ (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I've tried looking at answers to similar questions, but none of the solutions seem to work.

What could be the problem?

Comment: include <string> not <cstring>

Comment: It's because you're using space indentation. Philistine.

Comment: Could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755484/stoi-and-stdto-string-on-mingw-4-7-1

Comment: So it's just not implemented in Windows? ... Thank's @chris!